# Kivy Application is not launching with console option "FALSE"

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller

Kivy Application for Windows-7(32-bit) is crashing when trying to run with console option "False".I have used Pyinstaller for creating ".exe" file. Can anybody suggest anything for the same?

P.S: Application is working fine with console option "True"

Comment: Are you printing to the console inside of your app?

Comment: Thanks for replying. No,I have removed all the print statements from my python file.